# Backing up MySQL Databases

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, database-backups

I'm running MySQL 8.0 on a Windows 10 PC. Also using MySQL Workbench.

I back all my important data using Google Drive. However I've got lots of data on various MySQL databases and I don't know where this data is stored on my PC or how to back it up. Can anyone help here please? (preferably in the background, or as some kind of automated daily thing)

Thank you.

Comment: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\dumps\ but basically you can save it anywhere and for you daily backups, run the **task scheduler** and run a **mysqldunmp batch file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know where the data is stored, because you should not back up MySQL data using normal file copying.

You can find your MySQL datadir using an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT @@datadir;
```

But if you do a drag & drop file copy of the files in the datadir while MySQL Server is active, you'll get a corrupt backup. The reason is that MySQL Server may be writing data even while no queries are running. If you try to copy files, this may read some data files out of sync with the latest changes. So the backup will have some files that were made before the change, and other files after the latest change. Trying to restore this backup will result in an unusable set of files.

The only safe way to do file copying to back up your MySQL data directly from the datadir is to stop the MySQL Server service first.

It's better if you use a backup tool like [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to export the data in a consistent state. In MySQL Workbench, try menu **Server->Data Export**. This is a user interface, but internally it just runs mysqldump based on the options you give it in the UI.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work fine.